# Find alphabet neighbour letters in string (2 types: aABClg = ABC, aAbcd = aA)

Tags: python

EDIT: The problem, and the answer lies in using the enumerate function to access the index of iterables, but I'm still working on applying it properly.

I was asked to generate a random word with N length, and to print uppercase alphabet neighbours and lower - upper neighbours. I really don't know how to put this better.
The example is in the title, here is my code so far, and I think it works, I just need to fix the error made by the index search in the ascii_uppercase list variable.

Also, please excuse the messy do - while loop at the beginning.

```
import string
import random
 
letters = list(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase)
 
enter = int(input('N: '))
def randomised(signs = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase, X = enter):
        return( ''.join(random.choice(signs) for _ in range(X)))
 
if enter == 1:
    print('END')
   
while enter > 1:
    enter = int(input('N: '))
    word1 = randomised()
    word2 = list(word1)
    neighbour = ''
    same = ''
    for j in word2:
        if word2[j] and word2[j+1] in string.ascii_uppercase and letters.index(j) == word2.index(j) and letters.index(j+1) == word2.index(j+1):
            same += j
            same += j+1
           
    for i in word2:
        if word2[i] == i.upper and word2[i+1] == (i+1).upper:
            neighbour += i
            neighbour += i+1
    print('Created: {}, Neighbour uppercase letters: {}, Neighbour same letters: {}' .format(word1,same,neighbour))
```

expected behaviour:

```
N: 7
Created: aaBCDdD, Neighbour uppercase letters: BCD, Neighbour same letters: dD
N: 1
N: END
```

Comment: Might be more explicit to translate your variable names to English ;) also please better describe the expected behavior

Comment: @mozway thanks for the suggestion, updated

Comment: You iterate on the characters but consider it as the indices. If you want to get index and character use: `for idx, char in enumerate(word):`

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure, but i think your problem might stem from the use of "i+1" and "j+1" without limiting the iterations stop before the last one.

The next thing is that you need to put this code in english for people to be able to provide better answers, i am not native english, but the core of my code is in english so it will be understandable worldwide, there are other general improvements that can be done, but those are learn while coding.

I hope your assignment goes great.

Another recommendation you can use "a".islower() to see if the character is lowercase, isupper() to se if it is uppercase, you don't need to import the whole alphabet. There are many builtin functions to deal with common scenarios and those tend to be more efficient than what most people would do without them.

Edit: the error is because you are doing string + number

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, im not sure why it isn't visible but i've already translated the whole assignment to english, also since i imported the whole ascii library anyway to create a random word, i chose to use it, along with the fact that i haven't been taught certain techniques such as .islower .isupper

Comment: ok, then don't use them, your teacher might want for you to find your method before using builtin methods, although one thing you might want to do is to save them in a variable instead of calling them every time.

Comment: going back top your problem (i might have commented while you were translating the code), i think the error is in line 20, because j is an string, you can't add an int to a string. i will say to add this 2 lines to your code after "word2 = list(word1)" "for i in word1: print(i)" "for i in word2: print(i)"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working code (without formatting of the output). I used a simple pairwise iteration to compare each character with the previous one.

```
# generation of random word
N = 50
word = ''.join(random.choices(ascii_letters, k=N))

# forcing word for testing
word = 'aaBCDdD'

# test of conditions
cond1 = ''
cond2 = ''
flag1 = False  # flag to add last character of stretch

for a,b in zip('_'+word, word+'_'):
    if a.isupper() and b.isupper() and ord(a) == ord(b)-1:
        cond1 += a
        flag1 = True
    elif flag1:
        flag1 = False
        cond1 += a
    if a.islower() and b.isupper() and a.lower() == b.lower():
        cond2 += a+b

print(cond1, cond2, sep='\n')
# BCD
# dD
```

*NB. In case the conditions are met several times in the word, the identified patterns will just be concatenated*

Example on random word of 500 characters:

```
IJRSOPHILMMNVW
kKdDyY
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback, unfortunately i can't use it as we haven't been taught the zip function in my college course

Comment: @OrdinaryMind33 you can emulate the same with iteration on the index, give it a try as an exercice ;)